# dart mixin 'with' cannot be used without 'extends'?

Tags: syntax, dart, mixins

I'm working in Webstorm 6.0.2 and getting an error when trying to use mixin syntax:

```dart
class A{}

class B with A{} //error can't use with syntax without an extends?
```

Why can't I use `with` without `extends`?  Surely every class implicitly `extends Object`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's [a really clear explanation from Ladislav Thon](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/8N3peoP265A/w0-_IZut3NMJ) :

> [...] there's a simple advice, which is actually semantically correct: in the declaration *class C extends SC with M1, M2, M3 implements I1, I2 { ... }*, imagine parenthesis around the content of the extends clause. They will look like this: *class C extends (SC with M1, M2, M3) implements I1, I2 { ... }*. Which means that class C doesn't extend SC, it extends SC_with_M1_with_M2_with_M3.
>
> Or, put another way: the class declaration has an *extends* clause and an *implements* clause, but it **doesn't** have a *with* clause. Instead, the *with* clause belongs inside the *extends* clause.

And [another point from Florian Loitsch](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/seJMycuZ2MU/s4TO2U6xpp4J) :

> When you extend "Object" with a mixin the first mixin can always take the place of "Object".

So your `class B with A` should be `class B extends Object with A` that is also equivalent to `class B extends A`.

Comment: when it says mixins must extend from object does that mean that (in the original question example) A must extend object or B must extend object, or both? I gues what I'm asking is which is considered the mixin A or B I was thinking it was A

Comment: See http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/#syntax-and-semantics for restrictions on `A`.